# Cast timestamp to integer in Redshift

Tags: sql, database, time, casting, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to cast or convert a timestamp column to an integer value in a Redshift database. I know it is possible in other SQL-based databases and I've done this before, however in Redshift I can't get it to work.

I've tried some variations of `cast` and also `convert` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html).

Here is an example:

`SELECT cast(finish_time as integer) FROM table;`

It gives me the error message:

`SQL Error Invalid operation: cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to integer;`

Is it possible to get a timestamp as an integer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try `select extract('epoch' from finish_time)`, it will give you Unix ms timestamp

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @AlexYes However i am not able to use this epoch timestamp in order by clause to sort the rows. Any help in that.

Comment: @jeevs please ask a question with the code sample and `amazon-redshift` tag